# Seeded Questions Set to CW

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, policy, seeded-questions

I tend to think that maybe seeded questions should be CW. Not that I care about rep being given for seeded questions because they are helping the site, and rep should be awarded for helping out. But in general, something makes me feel dirty for asking a bunch of seeded questions and getting rep.

Edit: I mean in the case when the poster intends on answering their own question.

I don't know if this is even worth fussing over, but whatever, discuss.

Comment: Down voting the idea or the question?

Answer (score 6):

If a seeded question is community wiki, then the answers become community wiki and no-one has any incentive to answer it. The main issue is that if you are going to seed questions make them high quality and not just copy pastes of each other or other people's question's. Writing good questions is hard and deserves some reward.

Comment: I'd say that while self-answering one's seeded question, CW is good etiquette.

Comment: It's explicitly-allowed practice on SO (per the FAQ) to answer your own question.  I'm pretty sure you don't get 15 points for accepting your own answer, though.

Comment: @Akhil this was the situation I had in mind, I will edit the question to reflect that. Also, when people refer to you, do you prefer Akhil, Matthew, Matt, or Fella? :)

Comment: @BBischof: I prefer Akhil. Mainly because the others are fairly ambiguous =P.

Answer (score 3):

While I do think it's rather underhanded that seeders get reputation, Community Wiki is for a specific purpose.  Someone entering the site and seeing all these (hopefully well-written and on-topic) seeded questions would be quite confused as to the role of CW.

Comment: This is an interesting point I hadn't considered, hmm.

Answer (score 3):

One reasonable thing to do is to just ask a question and give other users some time to answer it. If no suitable answers appear, you can write your own and (in my opinion) you'll deserve the reputation you'll earn from writing the answer.

(One thing that I'd definitely avoid is writing the answer before posting the question, in order to give everyone at least a somewhat-fair shot at answering the question.)

Comment: If you intend to self answer your question, you need to give people either a long gap to try and answer the question, or post the question and answer almost simultaneously so that people are aware of your answer before they start writing their's. Anything in between results in a lot of people wasting time.

Comment: I agree with Ben. For example, Katie's question/answer on determinants was very useful, but she posted them within 2 minutes of each other. I know I am somewhat slow, but I doubt anyone can write all that in 2 minutes...

Answer (score 2):

A merge of Justin and Casebash's solutions: Make the answer CW if you're answering your own question, which in addition to solving the getting-rep issue (if one thinks it is one) allows others to edit it. Which makes sense in the case of many seeded self-answered questions, which are trying to be the canonical answers in a sense--and so that others can improve on your answer in ways you haven't thought of. Don't CW the question, because that confuses the purpose of CW for new users: an isolated CW answer makes sense in more cases than a CW question.

Comment: #@%! I can't un-community-wiki my stupid Lagrange multipliers seed!  (Maybe it will get shut down anyhow...)  I like the idea of seeds and I like the idea of developing the canonical answer.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, community-wiki-izing is irreversible. See the [StackOverflow faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741). In the long run, the effect will be negligible.